# How do I remove keyword highlighting within comments in Intellij?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, comments, keyword

[image: https://imgur.com/4rAcKNa]

I have a keyword "end" within a comment in Ruby. How do I disable highlighting of keywords when in a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Please uncheck option **Settings | Editor | General| Appearance-> Highlight RDoc and ruby syntax in comments** and restart IntelliJ IDEA.